# How to put and get type T argument in fragment newInstance

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragments

What is proper and best way to put and then (more importantly) get argument of type T and also List of T in fragment in android? I'm using PagerFragment for different types of entities and their list. This code seems to work but I can see that on some of devices there is java.lang.ClassCastException in onCreate. Any advice would be really appreciated.

I do this now like this:

```
class PagerFragment<T>(): Fragment() {
    private var arraylist: ArrayList<T>? = null
    private var type: Int = 0
    private var extra = false
    private var entity: T? = null

    companion object{
        fun <T: Parcelable> newInstance(type: Int, arraylist: ArrayList<T>, entity: T? = null, canContact: Boolean = true): Fragment {
            return PagerFragment<T>().apply {
                arguments = Bundle(4).apply {
                    putParcelable(ARG_ARRAYLIST, BaseParcelable(arraylist))
                    putInt(ARG_TYPE, type)
                    putBoolean(ARG_EXTRA, canContact)
                    putParcelable(ARG_ENTITY, entity)
                }
            }
        }
    }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            type = it.getInt(ARG_TYPE)
            arraylist = it.getParcelable<BaseParcelable>(ARG_ARRAYLIST)?.value as ArrayList<T> // warning here - Unchecked cast: Any? to kotlin.collections.ArrayList<T> /* = java.util.ArrayList<T> */
            entity = it.get(ARG_ENTITY) as T // warning here - Unchecked cast: Any? to T
            // extras
            extra = it.getBoolean(ARG_EXTRA)
        }
    }

...
}

class BaseParcelable : Parcelable {
    var value: Any
    constructor(value: Any) {
        this.value = value
    }

    constructor(parcel: Parcel) {
        this.value = Any()
    }

    override fun writeToParcel(dest: Parcel?, flags: Int) {}
    override fun describeContents(): Int = 0
    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<BaseParcelable> {

        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): BaseParcelable {
            return BaseParcelable(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<BaseParcelable?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exception message exactly?

Comment: @AnimeshSahu it's java.lang.RuntimeException caused by java.lang.ClassCastException: at PagerFragment.onCreate (PagerFragment.java:4) on these devices: Samsung Galaxy S8+ Android 9 (SDK 28) and Samsung Galaxy A50. I got this from google play console so there is only trace stack which is not so meaningful to me

Comment: Perhaps the `arrayList` and `entity` could be retrieved by a ViewModel from a Repository? What is it that those two objects represent?

Comment: They are representing Member (name, age, etc) and arrayList<Member> (and 6 more other entities). I pass it to ViewPager. I didn't exactly understand what you suppose, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

After first comment edit:
Double check the output of your 'it.getParcelable(ARG_ARRAYLIST)?.value' variable, it might work on your emulator because your object in the emulator is different from the Operational one.(runtime issue)
Double check the cast and see what it is your are passing along.

`it.getParcelable<BaseParcelable>(ARG_ARRAYLIST)?.value as ArrayList<T>`

This is not an cast and could be considered even a Nullpointer exception.
Ex.'null as ArrayList' on runtime.

What I see is
a = p (Of which type?)

java/Kotlin does not know which type variable p is until it tries in runtime.

Example of an checked Cast would be

```
object p = new Pear();
Pear b = (Pear)p; 
Apple a = (Apple) p; //Class CastException.
```

Double check your variables, with an instanceof to check the cast, and make a unchecked cast to a checked cast.

Ex. checked casting.

```
if(p instanceof Apple){
   a = (Apple) p;
}
```

Your specific case ex:

```
    var list = it.getParcelable<BaseParcelable>(ARG_ARRAYLIST)?.value
    if(list instanceof ArrayList){
        arraylist = (ArrayList) list;
        System.out.println("Im a list of type: " + list.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }else{
        System.out.println(list.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
```

Comment: Um, thanks for the answer but this is not what I asked at all. There is a warning on these lines: arraylist = it.getParcelable<BaseParcelable>(ARG_ARRAYLIST)?.value as ArrayList<T> // warning here - Unchecked cast: Any? to kotlin.collections.ArrayList<T> /* = java.util.ArrayList<T> */
entity = it.get(ARG_ENTITY) as T // warning here - Unchecked cast: Any? to T
So I guess I'm doing something wrong with passing and getting arguments, though it works, for example, on emulator, but crashes, again for example, on Samsung Galaxy S8+ Android 9 (SDK 28)

Comment: updated answer to reflect comment, why am I hammering on casting? because this is what the error messaging is telling you.

Comment: I have like 7 entities that are using this PagerFragment and you assume to check each entity, 7 cast checking? That's not for type T it's supposed to do, right?

Comment: Well your checking with only 7 PagerFragments? thats not a very high count, either you do this or avoid to use the Generics <T> completely and use an interface instead , and check if the interface is on the item. also look up "Object Type casting in java".  and " How exactly do Generics work?"